# SSRS Report Throws Hexadecimal Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting this error in my SSRS report DataSet when i run it.

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
The server sent an unrecognizable response.
' ', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 15639148
```

Could you please suggest what could the issue for error?
I was searching so many sites, but not getting specific reason for this error

Comment: One of your columns in your dataset has a data type of hexadecimal but a blank space for a value. So either change the type or trim it.

Comment: Thanks Steven for your comment. I agree your point and i will check the each column. But here when i download the report and run that report from Report builder which connecting to my Production Server i can able to see the data in report builder but in sharepoint i am not able to see the data because of Hexadecimal error. Will this have any intended reason for this?

Comment: What result do you get when you run this query in the designer?

Comment: @ Lucky I am able to see the results in report builder but i am not able see the data in sharepoint and getting the error when i run it